# How to override setTimeout() and setInterval() to allow dynamic adjustments

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am debugging some complex animation stuff and sometimes I need to slow down time to see what is exactly going on. Since the code is very complex, modification of the animation code is not a viable option. Therefore, I decided to modify the `Date` class as follows:

```
let ___date = Date.now();
const ___now = Date.now;
Date = new Proxy(Date, {
  construct(target, args) {
    if (args[0] === undefined) args[0] = this.adjust()
    let date = new target(...args);
    return date;
  },
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === 'now') {
      let date = new Date()
      date.now = () => this.adjust()
      return Reflect.get(date, prop, receiver)
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
  },    
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
    return toString.bind(new Date()).call();
  },
  adjust() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

This works as desired for `new Data()` and `Date.now()`. With this simple modification, I was able to move on, but later I found out that the code is not running as expected, as some parts of the code were still running with the speed that ignored my adjustment. I quickly realized that functions `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are those that cause my problems.

How can I override `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` so I can adjust time dynamically, i.e. not just when the function is started, but also during ticking?

Comment: What do you mean by "*so I can adjust time dynamically*"? Just slow down by a constant factor, or something more nefarious?

Comment: @Bergi – dynamically – many options, one for example could be making a Chrome extension, where I can change the factor/rate (default 1.00)

Comment: Then probably you want to write your own timer queue that you can manipulate to your liking, and run it step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to approach debugging animations, at least in Google Chrome. Open Developer Tools, then from the top-right three-dot menu, choose More Tools → Animations:

[image: Screenshot of additional context menu]

This opens an additional pane in the bottom part of the devtools where you can [debug animations](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations). You can move back and forth over recorded interactions like a video viewing timeline, as well as slow down animations as far as 10% of their original speed:

[image: Screenshot of the animations pane]

You can read more about the whole pane on [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations).

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of this feature/option, but unfortunately, this doesn't suit my needs.